# Inequality of real numbers with exponent

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, inequality, lp-spaces

For $a,b>0$ are two real numbers and $p\geq 1$. Is the following inequality true 
$$|a^p-b^p|\leq|a-b|^p\;\;?$$

Comment: 5=|3^2-2^2| > |3-2|^2=1

Answer (score 1):

No, let $a=10,b=20,p=2$.

Then $|a^p-b^p|=|100-400|=300>100=|10-20|^2=|a-b|^p$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b\geq a$ then $\>b=a+\delta\>$ and $\>\delta>0$ 
$$
\\|a^p-b^p|\leq|a-b|^p
\\(a+\delta)^p-a^p\leq\delta^p
\\(a+\delta)^p\leq a^p+\delta^p
$$
but $a>0$ and $\delta\geq0 => (a+\delta)^p=a^p+\delta^p+\delta*x\>(x\geq0)($
Binomial theorem$)=>$
$$
\\a^p+\delta^p\geq(a+\delta)^p=a^p+\delta^p+\delta*x\geq a^p+\delta^p
$$
$=>\delta*x=0=>\delta=0\>$ or $\>x=0=>$
$$
\\|a^p-b^p|\leq|a-b|^p
$$
if and only if
$$
a=b
$$
or 
$$
p=1
$$

Answer (score 0):

Is

$$\left|1^2-\frac1{2^2}\right|\le\left|1-\frac12\right|^2\;?$$

Answer (score 0):

The result is true when  $ 0 < p < 1$

Comment: This might be true, but it would be quite more helpful to give a reason why.